# php mysql query to return results based on density of keywords matched

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a form which allows users to search a database table for recipes, they can either type the name of the recipe they are looking for or they can type in some keywords.

I am trying to figure out how i can check the records titles and return them based on the % density of keywords. so say the user searched "sweet and sour chicken" the results would find all the recipes which matched all the words first, then all the recipes with 3 of the words, then 2, then 1. Hope that makes sense :)

here is what i have

```
$keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['recipe-search']);
$search_keywords = str_replace("and", "",$keywords);

//Find The Latest Recipies
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $search_keywords);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) 
{
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) 
    {
        $searchTermBits[] = "title LIKE '%$term%'";
    }
}
$q = "SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE ".implode(' OR ', $searchTermBits);
```

which checks the titles that match each of the keywords but it doesn't find out the density of the keywords in the title. Can anyone help me with this, i'm stumped!

Many Thanks

Comment: you should use `preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/', ' ', $str);` this will replace multiple whitespace, and remove 'and' from the string. means you can remove that loop ;)

Comment: what so my query should become "SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE title =". preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/', ' ', $str); is that correct? not very good with expressions. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: no, replace you `str_replace` with the `preg_replace`  you query should be `"SELECT * FROM tbl_recipes WHERE title IN ('".implode("','",$searchTerms)."');";`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$keywords = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['recipe-search']);
$search_keywords = preg_replace('/\s{1,}(and\s*)*/', ' ', $keywords);;

//Find The Latest Recipies
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $search_keywords);
$likeStr = "`title` LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR `title` LIKE '%", $search_terms) . "%'";

$q = "SELECT *,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_recipes` WHERE ". $likeStr ." GROUP BY `title`) as `count` FROM `tbl_recipes` WHERE ". $likeStr .") ORDER BY `count` DESC;";
```

Comment: this query doesn't seem to return any results, i've tried several keywords but nothing is ever found. I've echod out $q and this is the query that is beig run. SELECT *,COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `tbl_recipes` WHERE `title` IN ('soup') ORDER BY `count` DESC; I have lots of recipes with the word soup in them? thanks

Comment: it seems to work if it matches the entire title in the IN clause so this doesnt work IN('Creamy', 'Broccoli', 'Soup') but this does IN('creamy brocoli soup','sweet and sour chicken') is there a way to make it work without having to match the entire title? many thanks

Comment: Hey, have updated answer, pretty sure this should work.

Comment: Actually... after reading your question again, this won't work, as your trying to find out tags from a title str..? you should really structure your database to use a relationship for tags.